# GridView Footer template manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

i created a gridView and it's databound to an objectdatasource the problem that I'm facing is with the insert command. I want to create a footer and usind that footer insert data to database. but when i put a footer template it automatically adds in a new column. Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ForeColor="#333333" 
    ShowFooter="True" CssClass="grid"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowPaging="True" Width="1200px" 
         AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridAltRow" RowStyle-CssClass="gridRow"  
        FooterStyle-CssClass="gridFooterRow" >
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
            ShowSelectButton="True"  />
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Insert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
            SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ElementName" HeaderText="ElementName" 
            SortExpression="ElementName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
            SortExpression="Status" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or how to add a commandfield in a footerTemplate

Comment: I think I've got the same problem with the footer creating an extra column. Just posted a similar question to this so I'll let ya know if there's a solution!

Comment: yeah got a solution and an explanation - check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660353/why-is-gridview-footer-adding-an-extra-column/15661538?noredirect=1#comment22228100_15661538