# Why is Gridview footer adding an extra column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can't believe I have to ask this - you'd think such a basic feature would be straightforward to implement, but I'm having trouble creating a footer for a Gridview. I've checked out various tutorials and other questions, such as [here](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/98_Adding_a_New_Row_in_GridView.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545919/how-do-i-add-footertemplate-to-gridview-with-bountfields), but am still encountering difficulties.

The problem is in displaying the footer properly (i.e. without adding an extra empty column). From what I gather, you need to put the FooterTemplate inside a TemplateField tag or it won't work - at least it wouldn't compile for me. If I insert this after the BoundFields columns then it adds an extra column which is not desirable.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true"
    CellPadding="3" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="both" CssClass="dataTable1"
    OnRowDataBound="Colour_Columns" Caption="PARTIAL COMPARE" ShowFooter="true">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="AntiqueWhite" Height="30" CssClass="header" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="AntiqueWhite" Height="30" CssClass="footer" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FOLDER" HeaderText="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FILE" HeaderText="File" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECKSUM" HeaderText="Checksum" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" HeaderText="Date" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" CssClass="updateButton" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Similarly, if I put it before the BoundFields it adds an extra column on the left. If I try to put all the BoundFields under the TemplateField it won't compile.

How do I add the footer to the gridview without creating an extra column? Also, while we're at it, how can I set its colspan to 1? (It's only going to have the one Update button in it, so no need for three columns in the footer.)

**Colour-Scheme method:**

```
protected void Colour_Columns(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Match")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "Mismatch")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == "New File")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;
    }
}
```

This method does not seem to recognize ItemTemplate values...

Comment: you have added one more template field thats why its showing you an extra empty column with a button in footer.

Comment: @CodeRider yes but if I don't add the TemplateField it won't allow a FooterTemplate...

Comment: exactly what you want? You are hiding few columns at run time. If you'll hide the column, then footer will hide itself. please elaborate, what you want.

Comment: @CodeRider As you say, the Checksum and Date columns are being hidden at run time because they are more for troubleshooting/debugging purposes. They also might be involved in the logic in terms of what gets inserted into the database tables. (It's been a couple weeks since I wrote that so I forget, I'll have to go back and check.) But in the meantime I don't want to delete them. All I want is for the footer to display without adding the extra column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using template field only for the last column and in that column you can specify the ItemTemplate and FooterTemplate. Try the code below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true"
    CellPadding="3" HorizontalAlign="Center" GridLines="both" CssClass="dataTable1"
    OnRowDataBound="Colour_Columns" Caption="PARTIAL COMPARE" ShowFooter="true">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="AntiqueWhite" Height="30" CssClass="header" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="AntiqueWhite" Height="30" CssClass="footer" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FOLDER" HeaderText="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FILE" HeaderText="File" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECKSUM" HeaderText="Checksum" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("STATUS") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" CssClass="updateButton" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" HeaderText="Date" Visible="false" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I changed the Cs file to read the value from the template field. Please recopy the ASPX to becouse I changed it too by adding an ID to the Label

CS:

```
protected void Colour_Columns(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label StatusLabel = e.Row.FindControl("StatusLabel") as Label;
        if (StatusLabel.Text == "Match")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        if (StatusLabel.Text == "Mismatch")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gold;
        if (StatusLabel.Text == "New File")
           e.Row.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I needed to add a closing bracket > and tag </asp:Label> to the label, and change "sever" to server, but that worked! Only thing is, now it's displaying the data, which I don't want

Comment: then make your STATUS field a TemplateField and footer to it. and leave DATE as before.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You can convert STATUS to a TemplateField instead of DATE. I will update the code, so you can copy and paste it.

Comment: can't. Status field sets the colour scheme. So if I make it a TemplateField instead of the boundfield, the grid shows up all white. I've tried the other ones too; they mess with the order of the columns and also tend to erase the colour fill

Comment: Have you tried to use both BoundField and TemplateField for Status, but set BoundFiedl Status Visible=False. So the color scheme can use it but you show the other one. If you want I can update the code in what I mean?

Comment: @Marseld yeah that still erases the colour fill

Comment: Can you post what you have in Colour_Columns method. I am guessing that is there the logic of coloring.

Comment: @Marseld sure no problem. Added it up above

Comment: I just changed my response and I added your changed CS to use the template field. Please retry that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `FooterTemplate` with `BoundField`. Footer templates are meant to be used in conjunction with `TemplateField`.Additionally footer templates are applied **per column** this is done so you can aggregate totals at the bottom of the gridview in cases where you have numeric data.

Here's an example of using template fields with a footer field in the first column, you can change this as required to suit your needs:

**ASPX:**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFolder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FOLDER") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    Footer content displayed under FOLDER, notice no extra column!
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFile" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FILE") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCheck" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CHECKSUM") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can stick with using BoundFields and add the footer dynamically in code:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        var footer = new Label();
        footer.Text = "Footer content";
        //Footer will be displayed under the *first* column
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(footer); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I just figured they could also be used like a reverse caption. Since I am using BoundFields, should I just add another row at the bottom and give up with this footer business?

Comment: It's up to you, you can either add some control right below the gridview or re-structure your markup to use TemplateFields instead of BoundFields, your choice!

Answer (score 0):

How to code this form:

PURCHASE ORDER MASTER
                                                                                                                          [lblPONumberH]                       
                       PO Number ://here is textBox //RequireField                  
                       PO Date : //here istextbox with Calender extender                 
                       Vendor: //here is dropdown
                       Created By ://here is textbox 
                             save//Button  Cancel//Button
             GridView

Item Description Budget Number Quantity   UOM       Price 
Databound          DataBound   DataBound  DataBound DataBound Edit & Del btn
 in footer style 
txtItemDescription ddlBnumber txtQuantity ddlUOM   txtPrice AddBtn